# CheckBox checked in OnBindViewHolder isn't checked when displayed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Inside my recycler item layout I have a `CheckBox` whose checked state I'm setting in `onBindView`. The problem is when the `RecyclerView` is first displayed, even though the first three items should have their `CheckBoxes` checked, they appear unchecked. But after scrolling down the list and scrolling back up, they are checked as desired. I set a breakpoint in `OnBindViewHolder` and the checked state is being set correctly every time. But for some reason when it's rendered the first time it's not checked.

**My RecyclerView Adapter:**

```
public class VideoAdapter extends ScrollBaseAdapter<VideoAdapter.VideoViewHolder>

    public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        CheckBox mBookmarkChkBox;

        public VideoViewHolder(View view) {

            mBookmarkChkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_bookmark_video);
                mBookmarkChkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        bookmark(getAdapterPosition(), ((CheckBox)v).isChecked());
                    }
                });
        }

    @Override
    public VideoViewHolder myCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_video, parent, false);
        return new VideoViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void myBindViewHolder(final VideoViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        holder.mBookmarkChkBox.setChecked(mCursor.getString(VideoListFragment.COL_BOOKMARK_ID) != null);
    }

}
```

I call `notifyDataSetChanged` every time I update the adapter's cursor.

**ScrollBaseAdapter(Parent class):**

```
public abstract class ScrollBaseAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    protected Cursor mCursor;

    public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor){
        mCursor = cursor;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
        View view;
        if(checkViewTypeFlag(viewType, VIEW_TYPE_LOADING)){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.progressbar_loading, parent, false);
            holder = new ProgressViewHolder(view);
        }
        else{
            holder = myCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
        }
        return holder;
     }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(checkViewTypeFlag(getItemViewType(position), VIEW_TYPE_LOADING)){
            return;
        }
        myBindViewHolder((VH) holder, position);
    }

}
```

**Note:** I've overridden the `OnCreateViewHolder` and `OnBindViewViewHolder` in the ***parent adapter class(ScrollBaseAdapter)*** to call the "my" versions of these methods in the ***sub-class(VideoAdapter class)*** which are defined as abstract in the parent class. But nothing fancy is going on in the parent `OnCreate` and `OnBind` methods, they end up calling the child `myMethods` even for those items in which the `CheckBox` aren't behaving as expected.

**Checkbox in Layout**

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_bookmark_video"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector_favorite"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/selector_favorite"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/small_button_drawable_padding"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/small_button_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/small_button_size"
    />
```

**selector_favorite**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_favorite_on" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_favorite_off" />
</selector>
```

**UPDATE**
To be more precise the checked state issue occurs unpredictably. After launching the activity on certain occasions the checkboxes appear checked, but other times they appear unchecked and i have to scroll down and up for the checked state to appear. Even in the times where the checkbox appears unchecked `setChecked(true)` is being evaluated on the checkbox. For some reason, maybe during some event in the recycler lifecycle it's being unchecked thereafter. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the checkbox's layout attributes. I had set `android:button` to `null` and `android:drawableLeft` to the state list rather than just setting the `button` attribute to the state list. I did this to get around an android checkbox bug where centering the drawable with `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` is impossible when the drawable attribute is set through the button attribute. Unfortunately using `drawableLeft` to set a checkbox's drawable meant that calling `setChecked` on the checkbox didn't always update the drawable's state.

Comment: I don't know why but this happened with me today too. And in past it worked with drawable on numerous occasion. But today all of sudden it stopped working for drawable but working properly for button!!! Thats really ridiculous and unpredictable behaviour